# Reverse engineering parameter value on subroutine call

Tags: gdb, encryption

I'm trying to find out what value a certain parameter has when it's called (I know "parameters" are gone after compiled, but you get the idea). The pseudo-C and assembly code are:

```
sub_171F4A0(ctx, aes_mode, KEY, &IV); // EVP_DecryptInit(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, const EVP_CIPHER *cipher, const unsigned char *key, const unsigned char *iv)

.text:000000000040CEE6 ; 252:   sub_171F4A0(v110, v125, ptr, &v130);
.text:000000000040CEE6
.text:000000000040CEE6 loc_40CEE6:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_40CAD0+363j
.text:000000000040CEE6                 mov     rdi, [rsp+400h+var_400]
.text:000000000040CEEA                 lea     rcx, [rsp+400h+var_1C0]
.text:000000000040CEF2                 mov     rsi, [rcx-28h]
.text:000000000040CEF6                 mov     rdx, [rsp+400h+ptr]
.text:000000000040CEFE                 call    sub_171F4A0
```

I have already figured out `IV` value, but now I need `KEY`, which is 16 bytes.

Then I ran `gdb ./executable` (Linux 64-bit ELF binary) and set a breakpoint at 0x40CEF6 and examined all the registers mentioned above (I have no idea which one holds the third parameter).

```
(gdb) break *0x40CEF6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40cef6
(gdb) run
Starting program: /path/to/executable
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000040cef6 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/4x $rdi
0x29d72f0:  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
(gdb) x/4x $rcx
0x7fffffffe340: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
(gdb) x/4x $rsi
0x1c11620:  0x000001a3  0x00000010  0x00000010  0x00000010
(gdb) x/4x $rdx
0x2a09690:  0x724a5bac  0xa90b86f0  0xff9d8546  0x9910582b
```

None of those values is the actual key, but $rdx seems to be the best candidate to hold the key value.

However, since it's a pointer, I thought I should examine 0x724a5baca90b86f0, just in case, which didn't work:

```
(gdb) x/4x 0x724a5baca90b86f0
0x724a5baca90b86f0: Cannot access memory at address 0x724a5baca90b86f0
```

Comment: >"I have no idea which one holds the third parameter"For the future: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your breakpoint on address `0x0040CEFE` and examine the memory pointed to by `rdx` at that point.

Comment: (gdb) x/4x $rdx
0x2a09690: 0x724a5bac 0xa90b86f0 0xff9d8546 0x9910582b (exactly as stated in the question)

Comment: So the value of `rdx` didn't change between addresses `0x0040CEF6` and `0x0040CEFE`?

Comment: No, it doesn't: http://pastebin.com/k2c2X1mL

Comment: Thanks. It looks like `AC` `5B` `4A` `72` `F0` `86` `0B` `A9` `46` `85` `9D` `FF` `2B` `58` `10` `99` is the key.